# Update multiple rows in access database using oledb parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I am trying to update multiple rows in a access database using parameters. I already have to code to insert to a database, but I need same type of code to update the database. 
My update string looks like this `Update tblitem set instock='value' where itemcode='value2'`
Here is my code to insert:

```
strSQL = "insert into tbltrans2 (transid,itemcode,itemname,qty,price,[total],btw) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\POS.mdb"), _
    cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTransId.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 10)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)

    cn.Open()
    For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items
        cmd.Parameters(1).Value = ls.Tag
        cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ls.SubItems(0).Text
        cmd.Parameters(3).Value = Integer.Parse(ls.SubItems(1).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(4).Value = Decimal.Parse(ls.SubItems(2).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(5).Value = Decimal.Parse(ls.SubItems(3).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(6).Value = ls.SubItems(5).Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next ls
End Using
```

Comment: Did you forget to update your code sample to show the update statement instead of the insert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should, at the most basic level, be able to modify your sql string to indicate parameter placeholders (?) as you did in your Insert query, eg

`Update tblitem set instock=? where itemcode=?`

The concept beyond that, eg creating/setting the parameters, is essentially the same. Hope I'm understanding your problem properly. Good luck.