# Update an MS Access  database in a loop with paramaters with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, parameters

I was trying to update a field called 'instock'( type is double in database), where the itemcode is a value (type is long integer in access database). But when I try to update them, I get a error which says 'Invalid index 2 for this oledbparamterCollection with count=2. Can anyone help me please?

```
 strSQL = "UPDATE tblitem set instock = ? where itemcode= ? "
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\POS.mdb"), _
           cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Double)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.integer)
        cn.Open()
        For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items
            If Not (ls.SubItems(1).Tag(0) = "n") Then

                cmd.Parameters(1).Value = (ls.SubItems(1).Tag - ls.SubItems(1).Text)
                cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ls.Tag
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next ls
        cn.Close()
    End Using
```

Thanks , + I get this error 'no default member found for the type double' while exucating this command:

```
 strSQL = "UPDATE tblitem set instock = ? where itemcode= ? "
            Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\POS.mdb"), _
                   cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)

                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Double)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Double)
                cn.Open()
                For Each ls As ListViewItem In SalesListItems.Items
                    If Not (ls.SubItems(1).Tag(0) = "n") Then

                        cmd.Parameters(0).Value = (CDbl(ls.SubItems(1).Tag) + CDbl(ls.SubItems(1).Text))
                        cmd.Parameters(1).Value = Integer.Parse(ls.Tag)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                Next ls
                cn.Close()
            End Using
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update multiple rows in access database using oledb parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111306/update-multiple-rows-in-access-database-using-oledb-parameters)

Comment: Use `Double.Parse` and `Integer.Parse` instead of a `String`.

Comment: I still get the same error even if I use this one 'cmd.Parameters(0).Value = Double.Parse((ls.SubItems(1).Tag) + (ls.SubItems(1).Text))
                            cmd.Parameters(1).Value = Integer.Parse(ls.Tag)'

Comment: no, I hvae some values in ls.subitems(1).tag

Comment: The values in `ls.SubItems(1).Tag` does not matter, but rather the type. `ListViewItem.Tag` is type object, `Double.Parse` needs type string. Explicitly cast it by using: `Double.Parse((string)ls.SubItems(1).Tag)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indices are 0-based in the .NET class library, including ADO.NET<sup>1</sup>

`Parameters(1)` means "the 2nd parameter" and `Parameters(2)` means "the 3rd parameter" (which is invalid here).

---

<sup>1</sup> This isn't true for *all* collections, but it is the most prevalent convention used these days. For instance, collections in the Outlook Object Model, which is COM exposed to .NET, indices are still 1-based ..

Comment: Thanks pst, I got another error, I have explained in my main question. Can you help me please?

Comment: See Tim's comment. Take one problem at a time. Note that **both** Parameters are declared to take Double values so make sure **both** are given Double values ..

Comment: no default member found for the type double is the error that I get after I tried. 'cmd.Parameters(0).Value = (Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(1).Tag) + Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(1).Text))'